# Test Logging Statements in an error handler

Tags: java, spring-integration, slf4j, spock

I created a custom error logger based on the type of MessagingException is thrown during process based on what the `InstanceOf` is in the payload.

```
    @ServiceActivator
    public void handleThrowable(Message<Throwable> errorMessage) {

        var throwable = errorMessage.getPayload();
        log.error("Error in Processing. Message: {}", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);

        if (throwable instanceof MessagingException) {
            var messagingException = (MessagingException) throwable;
            var failedMessage = messagingException.getFailedMessage();
            log.error("Failed Message: {}", failedMessage);

            if (!Objects.isNull(failedMessage)) {
                var msg = failedMessage.getPayload();
                var headers = failedMessage.getHeaders();

                if (msg instanceof File) {
                    log.error("Failed consuming File: {}", ((File) msg).getAbsolutePath());
                }

                if (msg instanceof String) {
                    log.error("Failed to create a CsvEmailInteraction from line {}. Line was: {}", headers.get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER), msg);
                }

                if (msg instanceof CsvEmailInteraction) {
                    var csvObject = (CsvEmailInteraction) msg;
                    log.error("Failed to publish CsvEmailInteraction to Kafka. messageId was: {}", csvObject.getMessageId());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a current working test. I've tried to bring in a `SLF4J Test » 1.2.0`, however the commented out part in the then statement, the logging list never gets populated.

```
class DefaultErrorChannelServiceActivatorSpec extends Specification {

    def serviceActivator = new DefaultErrorChannelServiceActivator()
    TestLogger testLogger = TestLoggerFactory.getTestLogger(DefaultErrorChannelServiceActivator.class)

    def "test handleThrowable with MessagingException instance of String"() {
        given:

        // Create a MessagingException with a failed message
        def failedMessage = new GenericMessage<>("This is a failed string message")
        def messagingException = Mock(MessagingException)
        testLogger.clear()

        Message<Throwable> throwableMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(messagingException).build()

        when:
        serviceActivator.handleThrowable(throwableMessage)

        then:
        1 * messagingException.getFailedMessage() >> failedMessage
//        def logs = testLogger.getAllLoggingEvents()
//        logs.contains("Failed Message")

    }
```

I only posted the String portion of the test, as they will be fairly the same with the logging messages being slightly different. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Feel free to link to a minimal Maven oder Gradle project on GitHub. Nobody wants to recreate your situation locally, making educated guesses about what your incomplete and missing classes realy look like. Thank you.

Comment: You create `TestLogger` against `DefaultErrorChannelServiceActivator.class` category, but your `DefaultErrorChannelServiceActivator` might be in different package, so its `log.error()` just is not visible for that custom logger.

Comment: @ArtemBilan - My DefaultErrorChannelServiceActivator is in my base package, along with the test itself. `com.my.package.structure.engage` and my test in is the same directory.

Comment: OK. I'm not familiar with that `TestLogger`, but let's see if that has a variant like this `TestLoggerFactory.getTestLogger('com.my.package.structure.engage')`! Otherwise I'd suggest to debug it to investigate what is going on. Doesn't looks like anything Spring related...